# Adding a libdef for a commonjs module exporting a function

Tags: commonjs, flowtype

I'm trying to add types for the micro library and its [main exported function](https://github.com/zeit/micro#microfn). I have created a libdef like this for it:

*flow-typed/micro.js*

```
// @flow
import type { Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from "http"

declare module "micro" {
  declare module.exports: {
    (): (fn: (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => void) => Server,
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use the main function with this snippet of code:

*src/index.js*

```
// @flow
const micro = require("micro")

const server = micro((req, res) => {
  res.end("Hello world!")
})

server.listen(5000)
```

In that code snippet the variables `server`, `req` and `res` are all typed as `any` even though the `micro` variable does seem to pick up some type from the libdef. This can be seen in this [coverage report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opR7U.png) created by flow. I've tried several different ways of defining the function but nothing seems to work. No syntax errors are found and the libdef seems to be found. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example from the [`flow-typed` definitions for `lru-cache`](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/lru-cache_v4.0.x/flow_v0.26.0-/lru-cache_v4.0.x.js)

In short, this should do what you want:

```
declare module 'micro' {
  declare var exports: (fn: (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => void) => Server;
}
```

Comment: It's also possible that the type imports are not working (I didn't actually try out your example). Try this out though.

Comment: It seems I have two issues. The first is wrong syntax for callable objects. That's fixed by changing `()` to `$call`. I want to keep the export as a callable object because micro exports other values on it. Second problem is that type imports don't work. The `http` module types should be built-in to flow so I can't figure out why they don't work. The express bindings import the `Server` type like that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer to your other question. It may be worth posting it as a separate question.